# Why is my account banned from asking questions on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, asking-questions, post-ban

This account of mine is banned form asking questions on Stack Overflow.

I don't know why this happen when I am at reputation 10 and later because of my positive contributions i came till 165 yet it remains blocked.

There is not much negative reputation on my account (only 4), and I have edited my answers later, but no effect.

Can someone tell me what exactly happening with my account? I know that it is the SO intelligence that deals with such kind of issues, but I can use help in ways to unblock my account.

Comment: Do you have deleted questions?

Comment: No. I dont have deleted questions. :(

Comment: Though i have two closed questions. I have edited them but no use.

Comment: I have read all that ... but i need to ask some advice how to edit the questions so that the ban can be lifted..

Comment: I hesitate to edit some of your downvoted questions, because I fear it would give them more attention and downvotes. Because looking at your overall questions, there are a fair few only asking for code/work, with you showing where you've gotten to. So should you get your ban lifted (and I don't know how much that would take) keep in mind that you should always try to demonstrate what you've done and where you're stuck.

Comment: Yes Bart.. But i need to have a chance to ask questions showing what have I done. BTW.. there are only 2 DV question

Comment: Sure. Thing is though, we can't tell you how much that takes. Experience tells me that you might actually have some deleted content weighing you down. (You'd be surprised how many users have forgotten about some) If not, you can't be very deeply into a ban. In that case, just keep contributing positively, getting more rep. The ban will lift, but it might take some work.

Comment: I am sure that I havent deleted any Questions but comments and answers some times though. so is there any way to deal with them now ?

Comment: I'll let a mod answer that. They might be able to provide a bit more insight. Until then, just keep contributing.

Comment: @SravanKGhantasala I have also the same problem... But my "ask question" and "editing" both are banned.. I don't know the how much time its taken... or I have to make a new account.

Comment: I have been waiting from say past 3 months or some thing more than that :(

Comment: @Sandesh With editing I think it times out. With asking and answering you must improve your existing content such that you get upvotes, you have the peer pressure badge, Sandesh, so your deleted questions are definately the problem

Comment: @RichardTingle So what should I do now ? Do I undelete the question to overcome this problem ?

Comment: @Sandesh It's case-by-case, can you salvage your deleted question? If so undelete, if not it'll just get more downvotes and you should concentrate on your other questions

Comment: Whats problem with my case @Richard, What should I do now ?

Comment: @SravanKGhantasala Your case confuses me, looking at your profile and assuming you have no deleted questions (either by yourself or by others) you shouldn't be banned. You've got a few upvotes as a result of the attention from this question. Have you tried again recently?

Comment: Wow.. Its Working Now.... Thanks alot guys.. You saved my life... I ve just checked 30 mins ago and its not working.. some magic happened in between... thank you all... :) Special thanks to Bart and @Richard

Comment: @SravanKGhantasala I have it on good authority that your ban got automatically lifted due to some upvotes you recently received on SO. But you're apparently still close to the edge. So try to keep your questions good. Otherwise you might fall back. Good luck.

Comment: Sure thing Mr. @Bart :)